# Disable CORS protection in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, cors

Is it possible to completely get rid of CORS protection in Cordova? I have several iframes in my application that need to be treated as the same origin as the cordova app in order for the iframe to have full access to the cordova apps scope.
Is there any way to achieve this?

It seems I have an edge case as everyone seems solves their issue with the whitelist plugin but this solves the CORS issue in the opposite direction and doesn't really help in my situation.

The app is only running on Android using the chrome webview if that makes a difference.

Edit: There are some [very old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272612/android-webview-disable-cors) going in a similar direction for Android webviews in general but they don't pose a solution and I was hoping something might have change in the last couple years.
If this can become possible by changing my webview I'm happy to do so.

Comment: Its a 5 year old question and only asking about the android webview in general. My problem is open to more solutions than would be possible for that particular problem.

Comment: So your question is similar to [Accessing phonegap inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18298301/295004) and/or [Can I use the native android camera in phonegap over an iframe and send pictures on my webserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40008012/295004)